# PDO filter along mysql_real_escape_string can work together?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

we are changing our functions to make our queries from mysql_query
to the pdo queries.

the thing is we have a lot of those queries... a lot.
So in some places we already have a query being escaped like this

```
$query_result = 
    my_mysql_query("select * from table where field = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($the_field) . "'";
```

and to avoid time losing on changing we wanted to keep the mysql escape

```
$query_result = 
    the_pdo_query("select * from table where field = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($the_field) . "'";
```

The question... Is this possible. Could be there further problems with this implementation??

Comment: *"PDO filter along mysql_real_escape_string can work together?"* - **A:** No. http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Comment: oh my friend... is that true??

Comment: *'tis* - I wouldn't lie about things like that ;-)

Comment: please search for pdo prepare statements. that is what you want.

Comment: This => http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements will get you started.

Comment: If you really cannot use a prepared statement and want to escape the values instead, you need to use `$conn->quote($your_value)` in PDO where `$conn` is your PDO connection.

Comment: If you're adapting your code, it's a great time to do an audit and make sure your queries are properly escaped. Prepared statements, if used in a disciplined manner, make his very hard to get wrong. You're not losing time by fixing this properly. You're saving yourself **tons** of time in the future if there's a mistake in here that blows up in your face. Just ask Sony how they feel about SQL escaping.

Comment: Okay so what is the point of changing to PDO here if you are not going to use the advantages of pdo?

Answer (score 2):

Use prepared statement:

```
$PDO = new PDO(...connection data..);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = :placeholder');
$stmt->execute(array(':placeholder' => 22));
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question per se. *"PDO filter along mysql_real_escape_string can work together?"* - It's drop-in code. [This...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129870/pdo-filter-along-mysql-real-escape-string-can-work-together#comment46485532_29129870) on the other hand; has. `has=answered`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, but this implementation is very great. Instead deprecated mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, use PDO->quote() instead, its the equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string ...almost.

be aware of: PDO::Quote adds the '' quotes for you, while mysql_real_escape_string does not, so

```
"INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($c,$username)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($c,$password)."');";
```

becomes

```
"INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(".$pdo->quote($username).",".$pdo->quote($password).");";
```

..but yes, theoretically, given that the connection encoding and escaping rules are equal, i suppose they could work together.. but why do this? makes no sense to me.

Comment: Using quoting manually like this is just asking for trouble, and is way more verbose than the alternatives. Use placeholders whenever possible.

Comment: the easiest way to convert mysql_real_escape_string code to PDO code is to use $pdo->quote .. it does pretty much EXACTLY the same thing.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the literal translation. The problem is that this is the wrong way to do it.